# In CMake, how do you change default compiler flags for a build type on a per-user basis?

Tags: c++, cmake

In cmake, the default release compiler flags for gcc are `-O2 -DNDEBUG`. I want them to be `-Ofast -NDEBUG`. And I want that to be true for every project I do things with in cmake without imposing that choice on any other consumers of my project.

How do I do that?

I could edit them into that project's `CMakeLists.txt` file. But then I'm forcing other people to agree with my choice. Also, I have to be really careful about how I do it to make sure that I only affect compilers for which that is a valid set of flags to use.

I could use `ccmake` on every project every time I check out a new tree or create a new build environment. But that's a huge hassle when I want to set the flags to the same thing every time.

Is there a way to set it up so that for me, personally, the default compiler flags for clang and gcc for the various build types are what I want them to be?

Similarly, it's noticing I have `ccache` and `gcc`. And that's fine. But it might be nice to force a different default choice for compiler as well, but just for me personally, not for anybody else who chooses to use my project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally set compiler flags in cmakelists.txt by adding an environment variable into my build script, then referencing that in cmakelists.txt.

```
#build.sh
export MY_CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -Ofast -NDEBUG -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unknown-pragmas"
cmake `pwd` -Dtest=ON
make -j9
```

Then in my CMakeLists.txt, I'll have the following line:

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} $ENV{MY_CXXFLAGS}")
```

It's simple then to pass arguments to build.sh, which is just a bash script, to change the content of MY_CXXFLAGS, based on the users needs.  (E.g. build.sh -b DEVELOP|DEBUG|RELEASE etc).

Comment: It's good as long as only optional (non-default) flags are expected.  I would strongly suggest that all default parameters are handled outside of variables.  It's very frustrating to start or resume a project and spend a half-day setting up environment variables or missing an environment variable and can't figure out why everything breaks.

Comment: Environment variables can be set within the build script, as in the MY_CXXFLAGS variable given in the example code.  So you don't have to spend a half-day setting anything up.  Your point is orthogonal to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

My current answer to this question is to create a global `~/.config/Kitware/default.cmake` file that contains initial cache settings and to use `cmake -C <path to default.cmake> ... remainder of cmake options ...` to run `cmake`.

In the process of figuring this out I initally named the file `~/.config/Kitware/CMakeCache.txt` and found something quite odd that appears to be a bug in cmake. I posted this question about it: [Why does this cmake initial cache file result in such strange errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399591/why-does-this-cmake-initial-cache-file-result-in-such-strange-errors)