# Why does this cmake initial cache file result in such strange errors?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a file `/home/me/.config/Kitware/CMakeCache.txt` that contains some initial cache settings I'd like to use everywhere. I run `cmake -C /home/me/.config/Kitware/CMakeCache.txt` and it gives me a parse error on line 3 with this file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-march=native -mtune=native" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during all build types.")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Og -ggdb" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.")
```

This is the error I get:

```
CMake Error: Parse error in cache file /home/me/.config/Kitware/CMakeCache.txt on line 3. Offending entry: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Og -ggdb" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.")
```

But, if I change the line (adding `=`) to:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "=-Og -ggdb" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.")
```

it works fine, but then the resulting cache file in my project has the option set to `=-Og -ggdb`. In fact, the `=` sign can appear anywhere in the entire `set` statement. But it results in different problems no matter where you put it.

If I rename the file to `/home/me/.config/Kitware/default.cmake` (or anything else besides `CMakeCache.txt` it also works fine and doesn't require an `=` sign in the value for every option.

This is very weird behavior, and I don't understand it. What's going on here?

Comment: The line looks good. I know it's the obvious, but did you try to save the initial cache file without encoding? Sometimes the `-` is not actually a minus sign (when copied out of a browser).

Comment: @Florian - Well, I was using emacs. And the line wasn't copied out of a browser. I typed it by hand. And that also doesn't explain why the exact same file worked when I gave it a different name. But, I'll try copying my currently working `defaults.cmake` file to `CMakeCache.txt` again and see if I get the same error.

Comment: Ah, I missed that one. Is your main `CMakeLists.txt` file in the same directory? Then the `CMakeCache.txt` file is loaded as you actual Cache file and the error is somewhat understandable (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)).

Comment: @Florian - Yep, `cmake -C ~/.config/Kitware/CMakeCache.txt -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` and I get a whole ton of 'parse error' errors. `cmake -C ~/.config/Kitware/default.cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` works fine and gives me exactly what I would expect. The two different files have identical sha256 hashes.

Comment: @Florian - And those two commands were run in a fresh `Release` directory I created under my project root. And my project root only has a `CMakeLists.txt` file and some `.h` and `.cpp `files in it. Try it yourself. My project root is in `~/src/employer/project_name`.

Comment: @Florian - My guess is that cmake used to decide what file parser to use based on the filename it was parsing, and they changed to a more nuanced approached but didn't fix everything, and so now there's something in there that says "Oh, CMakeCache.txt, those are supposed to have an `=` on every line so I can split them up into variable and value.".

Comment: You are right: see [`cmake.cxx`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L768): Anything in the command line that has the name `cmakelists.txt` or `cmakecache.txt` is taken as the path to those files.

Comment: @Florian - Looks like a bug I stumbled across. This weird "I'm going to parse it like a CMakeLists.txt file, except every line must contain an `=` sign." is clearly broken behavior. You should put your research into `cmake.cxx` into an answer so I can accept t. Though, it's bedtime now, so it won't be until morning. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

See [`cmake.cxx`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L768): Anything in the command line that has the name `cmakelists.txt` or `cmakecache.txt` is taken as the path to those files.

So CMake is ignoring your `-C` option here and tries to load your `CMakeCache.txt` as an actual variable cache file. And those files have a different formatting/syntax of `NAME:TYPE=VALUE`.

You can consider this behavior a bug in CMake. Or you just avoid using `CMakeCache.txt` for your initial cache file name.